# Tensorflow - Interpreting the tf.estimator.ProfilerHook "_Send" op

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have a deep CNN/RNN that I train on Google AI platform. I distribute the training on 8 GPUs using the `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy`. I recently upgraded my runtime version from 1.13 to 1.15 and my training is more than 2x slower than before. I read that `tf.estimator.ProfilerHook` can be used to identify performance bottlenecks. So I collected the profiling information and rendered it at `chrome://tracing`. I got this

[image: profiling screenshot]

A training step spends an entire 1 second on these `_Send` ops. What is this? I can't find any documentation on the op or why it's in my graph. What does this mean?